# Spring Mvc Message Bundle in Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, locale

I use spring 5.1.5. I use Java configuration and the message bundle does not work.

1. When I wrote it in xml everything worked as soon as the configuration was transferred to Java, the message *No message found under code 'jsp.header.entry' for locale 'ru'* appeared.
2. In xml config I can set `fileEncodings("UTF-8")` but in Java config I didn't know how to do this

A big request to help. Thanks.

It was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/locales/message"/>
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="false"/>
        <property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="lang"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="ru"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

It became

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.seeds.controllers", "com.seeds.validators"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    //Message Source config
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/locales/message");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(-1);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor getLocaleChangeInterceptor(){
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();

        localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeChangeInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionLocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();

        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
        return localeResolver;
    }

//others
```

Comment: Your names are wrong. `getLocaleResolver` MUST be `localeResolver` , `getMessageSource` MUST be `messageSource`. The name of the method is used as the name of the bean, so your java config isn't the same as your XML configuration. The message source and locale resolver are looked up by name not by type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both a `MessageSource` and `LocaleResolver` are looked up by name, respectivly `messageSource` and `localeResolver`.

When using Java based configuration [the name of the method is used as the name of the bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-bean-annotation). As you have named them `getMessageSource` and `getLocaleResolver` the desired beans aren't found and thus ignored.

To fix, change the names to `messageSource` and `localeResolver` respectivly.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com.seeds.controllers", "com.seeds.validators"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    //Message Source config
    @Bean
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource(){

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/locales/message");
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(-1);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver(){

        SessionLocaleResolver localeResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("ru"));
        return localeResolver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could still set the file encodings in the Java config.

```
messageSource.setFileEncodings(new Properties() {{ put("YourFileName.ru", "your-encoding"); }});
```

You use the `defaultEncoding` if no specific encoding is found in the `fileEncodings` field.
Since you don't use a specific encoding for your file, the default "UTF-8" encoding is used.

Comment: Grateful for the help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Java configuration is good as for encoding. But you implemented `WebMvcConfigurer` so you need to override `addInterceptors` method as your `LocaleChangeInterceptor` will be added to `InterceptorRegistry`. Please try :

```
  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
  }
```